# Is there a good way to implement a div cross which expands onHover?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

I need to display a cross in react like [this](https://codepen.io/Domino987/pen/PvLrRw) and each div needs to expand onHover.

It should push the other divs away or make them smaller. Does somebody know a good strategy to achieve this either with CSS or React conditional classNames?

I can only achieve on of those: The cross or the expansion and pushing away of the other divs but without the cross form.

I tired:
  `text-align: -webkit-center;`
with 
  `float: left;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are tons of way to implement it. Take a look at my snippet:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-opu88z

**JS**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      hoveringEl: 1,
    };
  }

  getWidth = (n) => {
    if(this.state.hoveringEl === n){
      return 70
    } else {
      return 10
    }
  }

  hover = (n) => this.setState({ hoveringEl: n })

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
       <div 
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', width: `${this.getWidth(1)}%` }}
        onMouseEnter={() => this.hover(1)} 
       />
       <div 
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', width: `${this.getWidth(2)}%` }}
        onMouseEnter={() => this.hover(2)} 
       />
      <div 
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow', width: `${this.getWidth(3)}%` }}
        onMouseEnter={() => this.hover(3)} 
       />
       <div 
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', width: `${this.getWidth(4)}%` }}
        onMouseEnter={() => this.hover(4)} 
       />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**CSS**

```
div.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
}

div.container > div{
  height: 50px; 
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: you can also create code snippet here, instead of linking to stackblitz.

Comment: @JuniusL. stackblitz for react apps win hands down with multiple files/scaffolding of folders, control over npm package, linting, etc etc. So also in the future I'll rely on stackblitz